# AWS S3 bucket policy does not define Put, yet it is allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public static website which images can be uploaded to. For this I enabled static website hosting and set Block public access to OFF. I then added this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1632669906301",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1632669869776",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This should allow anyone to access objects, but it is also allowing my IAM account (with Administrative everything) to upload, delete, etc. This shouldn't be possible. Why is it possible? And what else does this mean? That anyone can upload and delete from the bucket?

Turning on ***ANY*** combination of Block all public access prevents my IAM account from uploading, yet it can still delete.

Nothing makes any sense at all.

Comment: Please don't re-post. [AWS S3 bucket policy for get and upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/1082400/aws-s3-bucket-policy-for-get-and-upload)

Comment: It is not a repost, it is a different question. And does it affect your day to day life? Is it a problem to you that there are lots of similar questions on SO with slightly different criteria that might help people facing similar issues? Don't like the post, just move on and don't answer it.